Add method to a macro defined in a different package
For example, how could I add, in my own code/package, a method for the @test macro defined in the standard package Test.jl.
Doing the following does not seem to work:
import Test: @test

macro test(ex::SomeArbitraryType,  args...)
    ...
end

More concretely, it does not register an extra method on the actual Test.@test macro,
but just defines a new local macro called @test.

Macros do not have a concept of "methods", only functions do. Macros do not know the types of input arguments, they only transform code.

You can add new methods, but the types you can dispatch on are limited: Expr, Symbol, literal numbers:
julia> using Test

julia> @test 1+1==2  # macro called with Expr type
Test Passed

julia> @which @test 1+1==2
var"@test"(__source__::LineNumberNode, __module__::Module, ex, kws...)
     @ Test ~/.julia/dev/julia/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.12/Test/src/Test.jl:493

julia> function Test.var"@test"(__source__::LineNumberNode, __module__::Module, ex::Int, kws...)
         println("new method for Int")  # more specific signature
         return __module__
       end

julia> @test 3  # macro called with Int type
new method for Int

If x isa SomeArbitraryType at runtume, this is not visible to the macro. For instance, if we define f(x) = @test x, then the macro method for ::Symbol is called immediately. The macro sees the code involved in defining f, and returns other code which runs once f is called.
julia> macro Test.test(ex::Symbol,  args...)
         println("method for symbol")
         return string(__source__)
       end

julia> f(x) = @test x  # macro expansion happens immediately
method for symbol
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> f("something")  # now the expanded code is run
"#= REPL[10]:1 =#"

julia> methods(Test.var"@test")
# 3 methods for macro "@test" from Test:
 [1] var"@test"(__source__::LineNumberNode, __module__::Module, ex::Symbol, args...)
     @ Main REPL[6]:1
 [2] var"@test"(__source__::LineNumberNode, __module__::Module, ex::Int64, kws...)
     @ Main REPL[4]:1
 [3] var"@test"(__source__::LineNumberNode, __module__::Module, ex, kws...)
     @ ~/.julia/dev/julia/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.12/Test/src/Test.jl:493


Thanks! I forgot that macros do not see actual types.
